# How can I convert an Exchange property to uppercase in 'simple'?

Tags: java, apache-camel, simple-el

How can I convert a property on an Apache Camel *Exchange* to uppercase, in [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) expression language?

e.g.

```
.when(simple("${property.countryCode.toUpperCase} regex 'NO?'"))
```

But I am getting:

```
org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException:
Failed to invoke method: .toUpperCase on null
```

I have verified that my property does in fact exist via `.log("${property.countryCode}")`.

This shouldn't be so hard, to get `toUpperCase` in Apache Simple (but it is).

I don't want to have to do `toUpperCase` in Java, or Groovy, or whatever - there must be an easier way

Comment: using a case insensitive regexp isn't an option?

Comment: Yes it is, but it's a little messy. The regex in this case would be `([Nn][Oo])?`, if i understand correctly. Besides, there are other instances I would like to convert to upper case. Incidentally my property comes from an xpath expression, but XPath 2.0 (and the `upper-case()` function) aren't supported out-of-the-box by apache camel...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
.when(simple("${property.countryCode.toUpperCase()} regex 'NO?'"))
```